# Trying to dynamically update a second table depending on whats selected in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm trying to link 2 tables together that are on separate worksheets but i can't seem to get it to work. Excel does not allow me to copy/paste link as its greyed out when you select paste special.

Sheet 1 contains Table 1 and has all the raw data and new data/rows will be added to it daily. In column H of the table i have created a data validation 'list' with 2 options: 'PROACTIVE' or 'REACTIVE'. Everytime 'PROACTIVE' is selected on a row i would like that row to dynamically update/populate onto Table 2 which is located on Sheet 2, so only the rows that contain 'PROACTIVE' on Table 1 will show on Table 2.

My tables look like the below on both sheets;

[image: Screenshot of table on both sheets]

The file is also here on my Google drive to download:

[Excel File Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0FUMX_fxi4GYXVJMzFLb3JfT1k)

Can anyone help or is it not possible?

Thanks

Comment: can you share the excel file?

Comment: I have edited my question to include the excel file. I uploaded it to my Google drive, thanks

Comment: Will you ever clear Sheet1 and not other 2 sheets after data is copied from Sheet1 to either ProActive sheet or Reactive sheet?

Comment: Have you looked into a pivot table?

Comment: no the table on sheet 1 will always contain the data. for example I may need to delete a row of data on the table on sheet 1, and in those instances id want it to dynamically remove the row of data on the other sheets too. The proactive and reactive sheets will just be there to serve as an overview so nothing will be manually changed on the proactive and reactive sheets

Comment: I've also tried pivot tables, but its the one thing I really get confused with on excel